# perl socket: increment port if in use

Tags: perl, sockets, eval

I have the following code:

```
use IO::Socket::INET;
use Sys::Hostname;
use Socket;


my($addr)=inet_ntoa((gethostbyname(hostname))[4]);

my $port_to_use = 7777;

my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET (
        LocalHost => $addr,
        LocalPort => $port_to_use,
        Proto => 'tcp',
        Listen => 5,
        Reuse => 1
    );
die "cannot create socket $!\n" unless $socket;
my $client_socket = $socket->accept();
```

if i start this in one screen and start another one in the other screen, i get an error:

```
cannot create socket Address already in use
```

instead of dying, i would like to try using different port (increment by 1) until it can find the one to use.

I've try to convert the `die` line with `eval` but im not able to catch it

any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a tidier alternative which actually checks to make sure the failure to bind to a given port was due to the port being in use. It also limits the port range to check. If you use the code [in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38606605/100754), and, if for some reason, the machine is not allowing your application to bind to any ports, you are going to get stuck in an infinite loop. It may also cause your application to bind to ports that should otherwise have been left alone etc.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Carp qw( croak );
use Errno qw( EADDRINUSE );
use IO::Socket::INET;
use Sys::Hostname qw( hostname );
use Socket;

# These can come from a config file or command line
# See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Dynamic.2C_private_or_ephemeral_ports
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/39784/2371

my @port_range = (0xC000, 0xFFFF);

my $addr = inet_ntoa( (gethostbyname(hostname) )[4]);
my $socket;

TRY_PORT:
for my $port ($port_range[0] .. $port_range[1]) {
    warn "Trying port $port\n";

    $socket = IO::Socket::INET->new(
        LocalHost => $addr,
        LocalPort => $port,
        Proto => 'tcp',
        Listen => 7,
        Reuse => 0,
    );

    if ($socket) {
        warn "Bound to port $port\n";
        last TRY_PORT;
    }

    if ( EADDRINUSE != $! ) {
        croak "Cannot bind to port '$port': $!";
    }
    warn "Port in use, trying the next one\n";
}

$socket->accept
     or croak "...";
# ...
```

Comment: This will be useful, thank you! I am failing to find a resource for various such error types. (If they are in `Errno` I don't see any.)  Would you know some reference for it?

Comment: Ah, yes. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 4):

Use a Loop:

```
use IO::Socket::INET;
use Sys::Hostname;
use Socket;

my($addr)=inet_ntoa((gethostbyname(hostname))[4]);

my $port_to_use = 7776;
my $fail =1;
my $socket;

while ($fail == 1){ 
    $port_to_use++;
    $fail = 0;
    warn $port_to_use;
   $socket = IO::Socket::INET->new (
        LocalHost => $addr,
        LocalPort => $port_to_use,
        Proto => 'tcp',
        Listen => 5,
        Reuse => 0
    ) or $fail =1;
}
warn $socket->accept();
```

Comment: First screen works but on the second screen, im getting the error "Can't call method "accept" on an undefined value at perl_server.pl line 39" which is the line "socket->accept()";

Comment: but why would it break out of "unless" if $socket is not defined?

Comment: i think the one you had origianlly was more correct. but for some reason the second screen is having issue. could you try to code yourself and see if you get the error?

Comment: @ealeon have changed to a while Loop. Now it is working for me.

Comment: Don't use indirect object notation. That is, instead of `new IO::Socket::INET`, write `IO::Socket::INET->new`. Second, have you heard of `last`? It sure beats having a misleadingly named variable named `$success` being set to `1` on ***failure***.

Comment: @SinanÜnür Thanks for the hint. Have changed my answer

Comment: For robustness, may I suggest checking `$!` against [`Errno::EADDRINUSE`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Errno.html) when the INET constructor fails?  That's the only error for which it would make sense to increment the bind port and try again (vs. EADDRNOTAVAIL, for example).  Additionally, you'll want an upper bound on that incrementing.

Comment: thank you this works as well. ill go with the sinan answer though as it is more robust (explicit checking). appreicate your answer nonetheless